# Finding all surjective, linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we find all surjective, linear functions $f : [1, 5]\rightarrow [4, 10]$? I thought we could use the continuity of $f$, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=ax+b$. If $a >0$ then the range is exactly $[a+b, 5a+b]$ so you need $a+b=4, 5a+b=10$. Can you finish?